# Is there a way to change the zIndex on specific items in heremaps?

Tags: here-api

Currently on a page I am building I have heremaps as the background page, designs call for two elements on the left and on the right that I'm placing over the map element. Right now, when I'm selecting the options button on here maps to select the map view type and other options, those views get hidden as my right element covers it. I've noticed the here map logo has a z-index of 1. Is there a way to change the zIndex of the options button on the buttom right corner?

Comment: It would help if you added some graphic image to point to where you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you:

```
// assuming ui is instance of H.ui.UI
ui.getElement().style.zIndex = 999;
```

For more information see https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-ui-ui.html#h-ui-ui__getelement